# How to set alphabetical indexed uitableview for contact in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I am getting data from my phone book like below format:

```
{
  "pm_id" : "2",
  "data" : [
    {
      "pb_local_phonebook_id" : "3BB376E0-62B3-4256-A449-2504FCDDC9CE:ABPerson",
      "operation" : [
        {
          "pb_address" : [

          ],
          "pb_web_address" : [

          ],
          "pb_name_last" : "",
          "is_favourite" : "0",
          "pb_IM_accounts" : [

          ],
          "pb_name_first" : "Adobe",
          "flag" : "1",
          "pb_name_suffix" : "",
          "pb_email_id" : [

          ],
          "pb_relationship" : [

          ],
          "pb_event" : [

          ],
          "pb_birthday" : [

          ],
          "pb_phone_number" : [
            {
              "ph_type" : "Mobile",
              "ph_no" : "+919800000",
              "ph_public" : "1",
              "ph_id" : "1"
            }
          ],
          "pb_name_middle" : ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pb_local_phonebook_id" : "2DD6AF52-DCD4-4FBB-A033-F95357455422",
      "operation" : [
        {
          "pb_address" : [

          ],
          "pb_web_address" : [

          ],
          "pb_name_last" : "Affle",
          "is_favourite" : "0",
          "pb_IM_accounts" : [

          ],
          "pb_name_first" : "Rishab",
          "flag" : "1",
          "pb_name_suffix" : "",
          "pb_email_id" : [

          ],
          "pb_relationship" : [

          ],
          "pb_event" : [

          ],
          "pb_birthday" : [

          ],
          "pb_phone_number" : [
            {
              "ph_type" : "Other",
              "ph_no" : "+9199909095",
              "ph_public" : "1",
              "ph_id" : "1"
            }
          ],
          "pb_name_middle" : "Puri"
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
```

How can use this data to use for this methods for indexing as per the iOS contacts book?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Can you please share how are you fetching datas from your phone book?

Answer (score 0):

**I dont know how you get all contacts but Use this method for get all contacts in Array**:-

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getContactDetails:(NSString *)keyValue{


    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    [self accessPermissionToAllowContacts:addressBook];

    NSMutableArray *allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    for( int i = 0; i < ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); i++ )
    {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

        //Using this we get only those contacts details which contact has address

        ABMultiValueRef addressRef = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);


        if (ABMultiValueGetCount(addressRef) > 0) {

            NSDictionary * contactData = [self singleContactDetail:ref];
            [allContacts addObject:contactData];
        }
    }

    return allContacts;
}
```

**Then use this method for convert in dictionary to array:-**

```
- (NSDictionary *)singleContactDetail:(ABRecordRef)person {

    // Initialize a mutable dictionary and give it initial values.

    NSMutableDictionary *contactInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Use a general Core Foundation object.

    CFTypeRef generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    // Get the first name.

    if (generalCFObject) {

        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"firstName"];


        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    // Get the last name.

    generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    if (generalCFObject) {

        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject forKey:@"lastName"];

        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    NSString* mobileLabel;

    ABMultiValueRef phones =(__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));

    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++) {

        mobileLabel = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);

        if(j==0)
        {
            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j) forKey:@"HomePhoneNo"];
        }

        if(j==1)
        {
            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j) forKey:@"WorkPhoneNo"];

        }

        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMainLabel])

        {

            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j) forKey:@"MainPhoneNo"];

        }

        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
        {

            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j) forKey:@"MobileNo"];

        }

        if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
        {
            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j) forKey:@"iPhoneNo"];
        }

    }

    return contactInfoDict;
}
```

Comment: i am using #import <Contacts/Contacts.h> not Addressbook framework

Comment: Add this two Framework #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>